# Regex Replace text with @ in it

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some simple regex that should replace `@Username` to

```
<a href="http://google.com">@Username</a>
```

Though its getting very odd results.

**REGEX**

```
var msg="@Mr.EasyBB";
msg.replace(/@(.+?)/g,
'<a href=\"http://'+window.location.host+'/u=$1\">$1</a>');
```

can someone help with this small issue results look like this

```
<a href="http://google.com">@U</a>sername
```

Comment: *"Though its getting very odd results."* For example?

Comment: Seems fine here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AFWkd/)

Comment: You edited the result lol. It's only getting `@U` and not `@Username` as a whole. I think I need to look ahead till white space. but not sure how

Comment: The ? should be outside the (). `/@(.+)?/g`

Comment: Remove `?` is not greedy. `(.+)` will just do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.+?` is lazy matching - this will match as few characters as it can.

Try this. It will match as many non-whitespace characters as it can.

```
/@(\S+)/
```

Comment: Originally `/@(\S+\b)/`. Sabuj Hassan got the final version first, although both should work.

Comment: Thanks guys. I now understand lazy operators better :D I thought lazy was keep going don't stop until success which I get that now success would be the one character...those lazy sons of a guns :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
msg = msg.replace(/@(\S+)/g, '<a href=\"http://'+window.location.host+'/u=$1\">@$1</a>');
```